# How to connect my android app to wampserver in computer

Tags: php, android, wampserver

I have write a php file in my computer, i want to read it in my phone, 
I can successfully access to the file if I enter the url (my computer ip)/android/get_all_products.php in my phone's browser.
 But my app can not access it successfully, the app have the permission of internet and can correct read other content.
Why? Can you give me some suggestion.

```
        String content=new ReadOnline.DownloadTextTask().execute("(my computer ip)/android/get_all_products.php").get();
        Toast.makeText(this, content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The DownLoadTextTask is word well with other url.

```
11-03 20:05:17.561  17519-17540/com.example.jifa.testonline D/Networking﹕ failed to connect to /192.168.1.191 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
11-03 20:05:17.561  17519-17540/com.example.jifa.testonline D/Networking﹕ Error connecting
11-03 20:05:17.591  17519-17519/com.example.jifa.testonline D/AAA﹕ [ 11-03 20:05:17.591 17519:17519 I/LBE-Sec  ]
ActivityManager.GetContentProvider->settings
enter code here
```

Comment: Start to remove the .get() from your asynctask call.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, delete all the Denied from all in httpd.conf, it is not enough only change allow from none to allow from all

Comment: That is a very dangerous solution. Others should not use this.